# Вывод пути файла

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно при открытие файла вывести в TextView путь к открытому файлу, в данном случае изображению.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

`//Объявляем используемые переменные:
private TextView tvPath;
private ImageView imageView;
private final int Pick_image = 1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Связываемся с нашим ImageView:
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //Связываемся с нашей кнопкой Button:
    Button PickImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    //Настраиваем для нее обработчик нажатий OnClickListener:
    PickImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Вызываем стандартную галерею для выбора изображения с помощью Intent.ACTION_PICK:
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            //Тип получаемых объектов - image:
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            //Запускаем переход с ожиданием обратного результата в виде информации об изображении:
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, Pick_image);

            tvPath=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPath);
            //tvPath.setText();
        }
    });
}

//Обрабатываем результат выбора в галерее:
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case Pick_image:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                try {

                    //Получаем URI изображения, преобразуем его в Bitmap
                    //объект и отображаем в элементе ImageView нашего интерфейса:
                    final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                    //tvPath.setText((CharSequence) imagef);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }}<code>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

1) в `onActivityResult()` добавьте строку:

```
tvPath.setText(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
```

2) Создайте метод:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Источником является Dropbox или другой локальный путь к файлу
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Если нужно не только путь, но и имя, добавьте в метод формирование имени. 
Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!