# Ошибка при нажатии кнопки

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток, я пытаюсь написать программу которая будет зашифровывать и расшифровывать изображения. С таким исходником:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ryvkin.com.scrambler.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="@string/choose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnChoose" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/path"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvPath"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnChoose"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/decrypt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnDecrypt"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/encrypt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnEncrypt"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnDecrypt" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package ryvkin.com.scrambler;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btnChoose, btnEncrypt, btnDecrypt;
    private static TextView tvPath;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private final int Pick_image = 1;
    String filePath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        tvPath=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPath);
        btnChoose=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
        btnEncrypt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEncrypt);
        btnDecrypt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDecrypt);
        btnChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnEncrypt.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDecrypt.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //Обрабатываем результат выбора в галерее:
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case Pick_image:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    try {

                        //Получаем URI изображения, преобразуем его в Bitmap
                        //объект и отображаем в элементе ImageView нашего интерфейса:
                        final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                        tvPath.setText(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }}

    //Получаю адрес файла
    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {//http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602034/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { // Источником является Dropbox или другой локальный путь к файлу
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void chooseFile() {
        //Вызываем стандартную галерею для выбора изображения с помощью Intent.ACTION_PICK:
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        //Тип получаемых объектов - image:
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        //Запускаем переход с ожиданием обратного результата в виде информации об изображении:
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, Pick_image);
    }

    private void encryptFile() {
        try{
            filePath=this.getFilesDir().getPath().toString()+"/myDirectory/Encrypt.jpg";
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream((String) tvPath.getText());
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            byte k[]="CooL2116NiTh5252".getBytes();
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k, "AES");
            Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outStream, enc);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while((read=file.read(buf))!=-1){
                cos.write(buf,0,read);
            }
            file.close();
            outStream.flush();
            cos.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"The file encrypted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), (CharSequence) e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     }

     private void decryptFile() {
         try{
             filePath=this.getFilesDir().getPath().toString()+"/myDirectory/Decrypt.jpg";
             FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream((String) tvPath.getText());
             FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
             byte k[]="CooL2116NiTh5252".getBytes();
             SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k, "AES");
             Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
             enc.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
             CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outStream, enc);
             byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
             int read;
             while((read=file.read(buf))!=-1){
                 cos.write(buf,0,read);
             }
             file.close();
             outStream.flush();
             cos.close();
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"The image was decrypted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll, FileProtocolHandler "+"Decrypt.jpg");
         }catch(Exception e){
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), (CharSequence) e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnChoose:
                chooseFile();
                break;
            case R.id.btnEncrypt:
                encryptFile();
                break;
            case R.id.btnDecrypt:
                decryptFile();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Но по непонятным причинам при нажатии кнопки Encrypt прога вылетает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С вероятностью, близкой к единице, при выполнении строки:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream((String) tvPath.getText());
```

Вы получите:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: %FILE_PATH% (Permission denied)
```

Так как:

- У вас в `AndroidManifest.xml` не указано разрешение:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```
- Если это разрешение указано, но у Вас `targetSdkVersion 23` и выше, то Вы все равно получите это же исключение, так как разрешение `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` относится к категории dangerous и при `targetSdkVersion 23` и выше, кроме строчки в манифесте это разрешение нужно запрашивать у пользователя в [рантайме](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).